# Spring Boot + Spring Data + Maven Modules = IllegalArgumentException Not a managed type

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data

I am getting

> Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'clientSpringDataRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not an managed type: class com.foo.model.Client

The most important here is that clientSpringDataRepository repository do not recognize @Entity Client here as managed type.

My project is multi-module so:

```
\pom.xml
|
\model
   pom.xml
   /*com.foo.model.Client @Entity definition*/
\repository
   pom.xml
   /*com.foo.dao.ClientSpringDataRepository extends JpaRepository<Client, Long>" definition*/
...
```

The code worked when I was building the application to WAR. It also works when I run it via IntelliJ through main method. But when I have changed build to JAR and make java -jar  it fails during the start up.

My configs are:

a) Model

```
@Configuration
@EntityScan
@ImportResource({"classpath:model-context-core.xml",
                 "classpath:model-context-persistence.xml"})
public class ModelConfig {}
```

b) Repository

```
@Configuration
@Import(ModelConfig.class)
@ComponentScan(
    basePackages = "com.foo.dao",
    excludeFilters = @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE, value = JpaRepository.class)
)
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.foo.dao")
public class RepositoriesConfig {}
```

c) Service

```
@Configuration
@Import(RepositoriesConfig.class)
@ImportResource({"classpath:services-context.xml", "classpath:services-context-mail.xml"})
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.foo.services", "com.foo.utils", "com.foo.context"})
public class ServicesConfig {}
```

d) Rest

```
@Configuration
@Import(ServicesConfig.class)
@ImportResource("classpath:admin-rest-context.xml")
public class FooRestConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

  @Autowired
  private LocaleRequestFilter localeRequestFilter;

  // ------------- IncomingRequestFilter + Registration -------------
  @Bean
  Filter incomingRequestFilter(IVisibilityService visibilityService) {
    return new IncomingRequestFilter(visibilityService);
  }
```

e) Main

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class FooWebApp {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(FooWebApp.class, args);
  }
}
```

My entityManagerFactory is:

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.foo.model"/>
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="jpaPropertyMap">
        <map>
            <entry key="hibernate.dialect" value="${hibernate.dialect}"/>
            <entry key="hibernate.show_sql" value="${hibernate.show_sql}"/>
            <entry key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}"/>
            <entry key="hibernate.format_sql" value="${hibernate.format_sql}"/>
            <entry key="hibernate.generate_statistics" value="${hibernate.generate_statistics}"/>
            <entry key="hibernate.use_sql_comments" value="${hibernate.use_sql_comments}"/>
            <entry key="hibernate.default_batch_fetch_size" value="${hibernate.default_batch_fetch_size}"/>
            <entry key="hibernate.cache.provider_class" value="${hibernate.cache.provider_class}"/>
            <entry key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="${hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache}"/>
            <entry key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="${hibernate.use_query_cache}"/>
        </map>
    </property>
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="${jpa.persistenceUnitName}"/>
</bean>
```

I am not pretty sure if it is enough information. I have tried to make minimal example but it works for me. Here I need to rewrite existing application to Spring-Boot so tried extract most essential info.

It fails in point d) when tries to create IVisibilityService bean which contains reference to Spring-Data bean.

The question is what have I missed?

Comment: Your `packagesToScan="com.foo.model"` yet you said that you have `com.foo.dao.Client` entity class.

Comment: Can you add main class too

Comment: Sorry my fault. Client is in com.foo.model. Will fix it. Also will add main class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in persistence.xml file (which was used in project before). Spring was finding it and overriding spring boot entities.

Remove of persistence.xml helped.

Interesting that it was working with WAR format but not with JAR. But anyway works now.

Answer (score 4):

add org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan on your SpringBoot Main class...

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EntityScan("com.foo.model")
public class FooWebApp {
```

// This way it will scan your entity package and will be managed by Spring